# htaccess redirects images to changed new domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have Moved WordPress to a New Domain, My old domain all posts normally redirecting to new domain name but problem is images not redirecting to new domain name,

```
https://www.oldname.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image-name.jpg
```

I'm using this in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldname.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newname.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.oldname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Waiting your reply thank you.

Comment: Have you moved your images to new folder or directory?

Comment: Nope, It's same directory.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldname.com [NC] and RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldname.com [NC]  it have difference of www. I am not sure but change and check it